# Python pandas summarize round trip in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (~30 000 rows) count of trips by station code.

```
|station from|station to|count|
|:-----------|:---------|:----|
|20001       |20040     |55   |
|20040       |20001     |67   |
|20007       |20080     |100  |
|20080       |20007     |50   |
```

how is it possible to get df where there is a number of return trips and extra lines of return trips were removed, like

```
|station from|station to|count|count_back|
|:-----------|:---------|:----|:---------|
|20001       |20040     |55   |67        |
|20007       |20080     |100  |50        |
```

my solution is

1. make a duplicate of the dataframe
2. make a compound key, changing the departure and destination stations in the duplicate dataframe
3. do merge
4. delete unnecessary columns and rows.

But that seems to be very inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works even in the face of duplicated entries, and is quite fast (<250ms per million rows):

```py
def roundtrip(df):
    a, b, c, d = 'station from', 'station to', 'count', 'count_back'
    idx = df[a] > df[b]
    df = df.assign(**{d: 0})
    df.loc[idx, [a, b, c, d]] = df.loc[idx, [b, a, d, c]].values
    return df.groupby([a, b]).sum()
```

On your example data (and yes, you can `.reset_index()` if your prefer):

```py
>>> roundtrip(df)
                         count  count_back
station from station to                   
20001        20040          54          55
20007        20080         100          50
```

Timing test:

```py
n = 1_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'station from': np.random.randint(1000, 2000, n),
    'station to': np.random.randint(1000, 2000, n),
    'count': np.random.randint(0, 200, n),
})

%timeit roundtrip(df)
217 ms ± 2.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

(On 100K rows, it is 32.4 ms ± 333 µs per loop)

Comment: It looks like magic. Thanks! Can I use similar for an additional string column (lgot id) like this `|station from|station to|lgot tipe|count|`, or is it easier to cast lgot type to lgot id and concatenate with stations then use the suggested function

Comment: probably, but it's hard to guess without seeing an example... Also, remember to select an accepted answer and upvote all useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution which handles the cases without round trip.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"station from":[20001,20040,20007,20080, 2, 3],
                   "station to":[20040,20001,20080,20007, 1, 4],
                   "count":[55,67,100,50, 20, 40]})
df
```

[image]

```py
df = df.set_index(["station from", "station to"])
df["count_back"] = df.apply(lambda row: df["count"].get((row.name[::-1])), axis=1)
mask_rows_to_delete = df.apply(lambda row: row.name[0] > row.name[1] and row.name[::-1] in df.index, axis=1)
df = df[~mask_rows_to_delete].reset_index()
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my dataframe, there are trips without a return trip, so I get this error `Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported `

Comment: I posted a new solution (much simpler) which handles this case.

Comment: Ok great so maybe you can accept my answer or at least upvote it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `sort` the stations and pivot:

```
# the two stations
cols = ['station from', 'station to']

# back and fort
df['col'] = np.where(df['station from'] < df['station to'], 'count', 'count_back')

# rearrange the stations
df[cols] = np.sort(df[cols], axis=1)

# pivot
print(df.pivot(index=cols, columns='col', values='count')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
col  station from  station to  count  count_back
0           20001       20040     55          67
1           20007       20080    100          50
```

Comment: This worked for me, the resulting data is the same as Pierre D's solution

Comment: but a little bit slower and less robust ;-)