# Python pandas summarize round trip data in dataframe with an additional string column

Tags: python, pandas

Recently, I was helped in answering a question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65417494/14872543, but I do not have enough knowledge to modify the function to solve the same problem of getting the number of return trips in the dataframe if an additional string columns appears.

```
   station from  station to  lgot  count  
0         20001       20040  stud     22   
1         20001       20040   fed     33  
0         20040       20001  stud     44
2         20040       20001   reg     55 
3         20002       20015  stud     66 
3         20015       20002  stud     77 

   station from  station to  lgot  count  count_back
0         20001       20040  stud     22          44
1         20001       20040   fed     33           0
2         20040       20001   reg     55           0
3         20002       20015  stud     66          77
```

My solution, replace lgot with int lgot id(there are not many types of lgot ~7), concat with the columns "station from" "station to" use the function proposed in the solution. Perform the reverse conversion of the resulting dataframe. Maybe it's from a misunderstanding of how the function works

```
df.head()
    station from    station to  lgot    count
0   2030080         2030000     full    464
1   2030000         2030080     full    395
2   2030150         2030000     full    330
3   2030000         2030150     full    285
4   2030240         2030000     full    249

df.loc[df['lgot'] == 'full', 'lgot'] = '11'
df.loc[df['lgot'] == 'rzd', 'lgot'] = '22'
df.loc[df['lgot'] == 'fed', 'lgot'] = '33'
df.loc[df['lgot'] == 'reg', 'lgot'] = '44'
df.loc[df['lgot'] == 'stud', 'lgot'] = '55'
df.loc[df['lgot'] == 'voen', 'lgot'] = '66'

df['station to'] = df['station to'].astype('string')+df['lgot']
df['station from'] = df['station from'].astype('string')+df['lgot']

df['station to'] = df['station to'].astype('int')
df['station from'] = df['station from'].astype('int')

df.drop(['lgot'], axis='columns', inplace=True)

def roundtrip(df):
    a, b, c, d = 'station from', 'station to', 'count', 'count_back'
    idx = df[a] > df[b]
    df = df.assign(**{d: 0})
    df.loc[idx, [a, b, c, d]] = df.loc[idx, [b, a, d, c]].values
    return df.groupby([a, b]).sum()

df = roundtrip(df)
df= df.reset_index()

df['lgot'] = df["station from"].astype('string').str.slice(start=-2)
df['station from'] = df['station from'].astype('string').str.slice(stop=7)
df['station to'] = df['station to'].astype('string').str.slice(stop=7)

df.head()
    station from    station to  count   count_back  lgot
0   1003704         2030133     0       1           11
1   1003704         2030160     0       1           11
2   1003704         2031321     0       1           11
3   1003704         2030132     0       1           22
4   1003704         2030133     0       1           22
```

Comment: You should atleast show the work that you have done before simply asking for a solution.

Comment: OK I added, but it looks disgusting, like I'm working in excel :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pierre's solution no longer works from the other question; because, with the new data `df[a] > df[b]` fails as the fifth row is now less than the fourth row. As such, the best way to do this with the new data is using `.shift()`. Also, you can pass `sort=False` to your groupby to improve performance and maintain order. Finally, I have used `.reset_index()` and modified the the column variables for `a,b,c,d,e` according to the new data.

```
def roundtrip(df):
    a, b, c, d, e = 'station from', 'station to', 'lgot', 'count', 'count_back'
    idx = (df[a] == df[b].shift()) & (df[b] == df[a].shift())
    df = df.assign(**{e: 0})
    df.loc[idx, [a, b, c, d, e]] = df.loc[idx, [b, a, c, e, d]].values
    return df.groupby([a, b, c], sort=False).sum().reset_index()


roundtrip(df)
Out[1]: 
   station from  station to  lgot  count  count_back
0         20001       20040  stud     22          44
1         20001       20040   fed     33           0
2         20040       20001   reg     55           0
3         20002       20015  stud     66          77
```

Comment: I'll try to understand the code. I tried the function on my dataset and the first two lines were counted correctly and then there is a failure. `station from station to lgot count count_back
0 2030080 2030000 full 464 395
1 2030150 2030000 full 330 285
2 2030240 2030000 full 249 0
3 2030080 2030122 reg 225 0
4 2030000 2030240 full 211 0 `

Comment: @СергейШамсуаров the solution I have provided works with the sample data you have given. The new data in the comment looks like a completely different pattern. Kindly accept as solution and create another question. Make sure to include the correct data in your question if you want to get the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you I'm new to python and have been using stackoverflow for the first day. Is it normal to create a similar request with an extended date set app and an additional comment?