# Create Pandas Function That Identify The Journey as a single trip or a round-trip journey

Tags: python, pandas

i'm new in SO and pandas.

I have sample datarow here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/13CBSmfOEBxlBn-Jzyo1WGJU4xrydT9ts/view?usp=sharing

I tried to follow the solution from these answears :
[Python pandas summarize round trip in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65415068/python-pandas-summarize-round-trip-in-dataframe) and [Python pandas summarize round trip data in dataframe with an additional string column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65430324/python-pandas-summarize-round-trip-data-in-dataframe-with-an-additional-string-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I've success counting the trip that have transaction on the date columns, but I still confused because, its not follow the function created here :

```
    def roundtrip(df_passanger):
    a, b = 'c_station_in', 'c_station_out'
    idx = (df_passanger[a] == df_passanger[b].shift()) & (df_passanger[b] == df_passanger[a].shift())
    df_passanger = df_passanger.assign(**{a: 0})
    df_passanger.loc[idx, [a, b]] = df_passanger.loc[idx, [b, a]].values
    return df_passanger.groupby([ 'c_card' , 'date'], sort=False).count().reset_index()

PPnPP = roundtrip(df_passanger)
PPnPP.sort_values('date')
```

[image]

I proved it by seeing the dataraw and create the code just to make sure :

```
#pembuktian
pd.pivot_table(data=df_passanger[df_passanger['c_card'] == '1003011802063152'],
              index='trip_chain',
               columns='date', 
              values='m_deduct',
              aggfunc='sum',
              fill_value=0)
```

[image]

when you see it, the customer doin round-trip only for CUK-THB & THB-CUK, and for THB-KMO and KMO-PSG should not count because its not a round-trip journey.

The round-trip journey need to fullfill these rules :

1. customer's c_station_in to c_station_out and c_station_out to c_station_in are the same
2. it's happened on the same date

or, for no. 2, may be we can create a function when customer doing the round-trip journey :

1. on the same day
2. the next day
3. the day after tomorrow
4. the next 2 day
5. the next 3 day
   etc

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need suggestion if the function correct or wrong, and how to fix it. Also i've mantioned that I need suggestion how i solved the 5 points that I needed.